# Select rows to columns from table

Tags: sql, oracle, select, group-by, pivot

How to simply SELECT rows from VALUE column to get a two-dimensional table with 6 columns and 2 rows.

Below is the source table:

[image: RowsToCoulms]

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: see 'pivot' syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical solution to pivot a table over a fixed set of columns is to use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    row_idx,
    max(case when col_idx = 1 then value end) col1,
    max(case when col_idx = 2 then value end) col2,
    max(case when col_idx = 3 then value end) col3,
    max(case when col_idx = 4 then value end) col4,
    max(case when col_idx = 5 then value end) col5,
    max(case when col_idx = 6 then value end) col6
from mytable
group by row_idx
order by row_idx
```

Comment: What about if a set of columns and rows are not fixed in all cases? Is there any more generic solution? I'm not really familiar with pivot syntax in Oracle.

Comment: @GregB: the number of rows does not matter. But as for columns: in standard SQL, a query must returned a fixed, predefined number of columns, so columns cannot be created dynamically based on the data. You would need dynamic SQL for this, which is much more complicated.

Comment: @GregB: note that the above conditional aggregation technique is not Oracle-specific. This is standard SQL, that would properly run on most databases.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using SQL Pivot.

How to create the example dataset:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('SourceTable') Is Not Null Drop Table SourceTable
Create Table SourceTable (
    COL_IDX int,
    ROW_IDX int,
    VALUE nvarchar(100)
)
Insert into SourceTable (COL_IDX, ROW_IDX, VALUE)
Values 
     (1,1,'after 45 min')
    ,(2,1,'98')
    ,(3,1,'95')
    ,(4,1,'99')
    ,(5,1,'1.1')
    ,(6,1,'12')
    ,(1,2,'after 60 min')
    ,(2,2,'98')
    ,(3,2,'96')
    ,(4,2,'101')
    ,(5,2,'1.4')
    ,(6,2,'12')
```

How to pivot the data:

```
SELECT ROW_IDX AS MyIndex, [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM SourceTable) AS q
PIVOT (
    MAX(Value)
    FOR COL_IDX IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])
) AS PivotedTable
```

Result:

```
MyIndex    1            2   3   4   5   6
1          after 45 min 98  95  99  1.1 12
2          after 60 min 98  96  101 1.4 12
```

A pivot in SQL uses an aggregate function; here I used "max" but it doesn't really matter because there aren't multiple values for a ROW_IDX/COL_IDX combo.

It sounds like you might need to dynamically generate your columns, in which case you can use dynamic SQL to get the same result:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #headings
SELECT DISTINCT COL_IDX='[' + Cast(COL_IDX AS NVARCHAR(6)) + ']' 
INTO #headings
FROM SourceTable 

DECLARE @Columns nvarchar(1000) = (SELECT string_agg(COL_IDX, ', ') FROM #headings)

DECLARE @MyCommand nvarchar(max) =
    'SELECT *
    FROM SourceTable
    PIVOT (
        MAX(VALUE)
        FOR COL_IDX IN (~Columns~) 
    ) PivotTable' 

SET @MyCommand = Replace(@MyCommand, '~Columns~', @Columns)
EXEC (@MyCommand)
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #headings
```

Comment: @GregB The second option here will work for you if the set of columns and rows are not fixed in all cases.

Comment: Is the second option valid Oracle SQL syntax?

Comment: Good point, @GMB. I'm not sure; I started on this w/o knowing we were talking about Oracle. This is valid for Microsoft SQL Server 2017 when `STRING_AGG` was introduced, but you could have done the same dynamic pivot since at least 2008 using `FOR XML PATH` instead for the headings. Oracle seems to support dynamic queries with similar syntax, but I don't know what might need translating.